# What are G and A privileges in granted permissions to a sql database user?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm executing the following query to obtain the granted permissions for the user seen in the query:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, select_priv, insert_priv, delete_priv, update_priv, references_priv, alter_priv, index_priv 
  FROM table_privileges
 WHERE grantee = 'TRAMITES_USR'
 ORDER BY owner, table_name;
```

And I'm getting that in a view he has a 'G' permission for a Select privilege and he also has for several tables an 'A' permission for Insert or Update privileges.

What's the meaning of that 'G' and that 'A'?

Comment: G=GRANT, A=Admin

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That view isn't described in the main documentation, but it is mentioned in the various Gateway docs, such as the [Database Gateway for Informix User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tginu/database-gateway-for-informix-data-dictionary.html#GUID-F1996E71-72BA-4340-89C0-BC1DED6C8189), which show different possible values for different databases and doesn't explain them.

In the 19c [SQL reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Support-for-Optional-Features-of-SQLFoundation2011.html#GUID-3BA98AEC-FAAD-4F21-A6AD-F696B5D36D56) it gets a passing mention:

> Oracle makes this information available in the following metadata views:
>
> - Instead of TABLE_PRIVILEGES, use ALL_TAB_PRIVS.
> - Instead of COLUMN_PRIVILEGES, use ALL_COL_PRIVS.

If you go back to the [8i docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a67790.pdf) (!) it says:

> This view contains information on grants on objects for which the user is the grantor, grantee, or owner, or PUBLIC is the grantee. This view is included for compatibility with Oracle version 6. Use of this view is not recommended.

Comparing `table_privileges` with `all_tab_privs` ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jrnp_Jww)) suggests 'G' is equivalent to `grantable` being 'YES' (only appears for `select_priv` for two rows in my DB), but it's not obvious why `insert_priv` and `update_priv` always seem to use 'A' rather than 'Y'. Perhaps this was a distinction back in Oracle 6 and has no real meaning now.

If you're *really* keen to figure it out, the [view definition](https://dbfiddle.uk/a-YzWunH) shows how the values are calculated, but you'll need to dig into that to really understand it.

But as Oracle recommend not using it, it may not be worth the effort. If you really want to use `table_privileges` instead of `all_tab_privs` then you can probably just distinguish between 'N' as false and any other value as true.